# Stationary points of $f(x,y)=x \log(y)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, partial-derivative, maxima-minima

$$f(x,y)=x \log(y)$$

Partial derivatives:
$$f_x(x,y)=\log(y)$$
$$f_y(x,y)=\frac{x}{y}$$

Stationary points:

\begin{cases}
f_x(x,y)=\log(y)=0 \\ f_y(x,y)=\frac{x}{y}=0
\end{cases}

Solution: $(0,1)$

Hessian matrix in $(0,1)$:

$$f_{xx} (x,y)=0$$
$$f_{xy}(x,y)=f_{yx}(x,y)=\frac{1}{y}$$
$$f_{yy} (x,y)=-\frac{x}{y^2}$$

$$f_{xx} (0,1)=0$$
$$f_{xy}(0,1)=1$$
$$f_{yy} (0,1)=0$$

$$H_f(0,1)=\begin{pmatrix}  0 \ 1 \\ 1 \ 0 \end{pmatrix} $$

$$\det H_f(0,1)<0$$

$(0,1)$ is a Saddle point

Is it correct?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Everything is correct. Well done !